# What does -include mean in an Android.mk file?

Tags: android

I am a newbie to Android makefiles. While reading this [file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master/target/board/Android.mk#5)  I see a "-include" statement.

What does this actually mean to the build system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `include` simply means that another makefile should be included. The `-` means that if the file to include doesn't exist it will simply be ignored:

> We can also put a minus sign `-` in front of `include` (with no space in-between) to ignore filenames that do not exist. For example:
>
> `-include makefile1 makefile2 makefile3`
>   If makefile2 does not exist, then make will skip it, and no error will occur. In general, inserting a minus sign in front of any command tells make to ignore errors that might occur during the execution of that command.

([source](http://www.ugrad.cs.ubc.ca/~cs219/CourseNotes/Make/multMake.html))

Comment: Source is now outdated